# Mansory/Isotope not working with elements of different widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

As you can see in the code-pen below; there's a space right next to the first image which is not being filled, when there's other elements that can be put there.

I haven't found any solution that had the elements width defined in percentage.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXEMaz

Html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
<div class=" isotope row  gutter">
                    <div class="grid-sizer col-2 mosaic-item">  
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-1 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></img>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-1 ,
.col-1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-2 ,
.col-2 {
    width: 49.99%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .col-2 ,
    .col-2 {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-2 ,
    .col-2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.col-1 ,
.col-2{
    float: left;
}
.gutter>div{
  padding: 10px;
}

.gutter img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   isotope();
 });
function isotope(){
var $portfolio = $('.isotope');
       $portfolio.imagesLoaded(function() {
           $portfolio.isotope({
               isOriginLeft: true,
               stagger: 30,
               masonry: {
                 percentPosition: true
               }
           });
           $portfolio.isotope();

       });
}
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: this code in css: `gutter>div` is used to space out the blocks. Can you post an image of what you are after please?

Comment: The gutter>div is being used just to space them a bit, but the problem is the big empty space that can be filled. Here's the image: http://imgur.com/a/Cohn9 I was hoping the space in red would be filled, becouse there are images that fit there. I dont want to switch the elements order. Basically, I dont want any white space when there can be images there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? All i did was add in another 2 column block after the very first one. Check code in full screen mode to see the columns work.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   isotope();
 });
function isotope(){
var $portfolio = $('.isotope');
       $portfolio.imagesLoaded(function() {
           $portfolio.isotope({
               isOriginLeft: true,
               stagger: 30,
               masonry: {
                 percentPosition: true
               }
           });
           $portfolio.isotope();

       });
}
```

```css
.col-1 ,
.col-1 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-2 ,
.col-2 {
    width: 49.99%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .col-2 ,
    .col-2 {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-2 ,
    .col-2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.col-1 ,
.col-2{
    float: left;
}
.gutter>div{
  padding: 10px;
}

.gutter img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
<div class=" isotope row  gutter">
                    <div class="grid-sizer col-2 mosaic-item">  
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                      
                    </div>
                   <div class="grid-sizer col-2 mosaic-item">  
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                      
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-1 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></img>
                    </div>
 <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>
                  
                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></img>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-2 mosaic-item ">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350"></img>
                    </div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to add extra imgs or change their current order, I want it to be dynamic. I want mansory to optimize the space used, so there will be the least possible white space in the grid, I dont mind white space at the bottom.

Comment: It all depends on the CSS that you are using. If you are using a two column div then it will leave a space on the side as the blocks are coded that way.

Comment: Doesnt mansory organize the imgs so it keeps the white space to a minimum? Becouse that white space can easilly be filled by just moving one of the imgs to there (the last img which col-2 and has the same height).